# Plugins are not installed in qgis 1.8.0 Lisboa

Tags: qgis-plugins, error

I am trying to install plugins in qgis1.8.0 Lisboa but error message is appear as follows,

> Failed to unzip the plugin package. Probably it's broken or missing
>   from the repository. You may also want to make sure that you have
>   write permission to the plugin directory:
>   /home/hebert/.qgis//python/plugins

Please tell me solution for it.

Comment: do you get this with all the plugins? Which did you try? Did you compile qgis yourself?

Comment: Same issue. Tried chmod but no joy.
Note /.qgis//python/plugins double // in path

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have write permissions and ownership on the `.qgis` directory

try running following commands:

```
sudo chmod 755 ~/.qgis

sudo chown -R <your username> ~/.qgis
```

Comment: It would be a major screwup if this wasn't already the case. Still worth a check though.

Comment: Thank you. It works for me, in ubuntu 12.10 and Qgis 1.8.